# Fortran float changing value of integer

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have noticed a bug in a code that I use, demonstrated by the following test code:

```
PROGRAM test

implicit none


integer(kind=8):: i

i=17159401
print*,i,float(i)


end program test
```

The code outputs `17159401   17159400.0`, whereas it should output `17159401   17159401.0`

I'm using gfortran:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/apps/gcc/4.8.2/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-gmp-include=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-obj/../gcc-4.8.2/our-gmp --with-gmp-lib=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-obj/../gcc-4.8.2/our-gmp --with-mpc-include=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-obj/../gcc-4.8.2/our-mpc/src --with-mpc-lib=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-obj/../gcc-4.8.2/our-mpc/src/.libs --with-mpfr-include=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-obj/../gcc-4.8.2/our-mpfr/src --with-mpfr-lib=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-obj/../gcc-4.8.2/our-mpfr/src/.libs
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default real type does not have sufficient accuracy here.

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: i10 = selected_int_kind(10)
  integer, parameter :: r15 = selected_real_kind(15)
  integer(kind=i10):: i
  real :: r
  real(kind=r15) :: s
  i=17159401
  r = i
  print *, 'default real kind: r', r, 'r+1', r+1, 'r-1', r-1
  s = i
  print *, 'r15 real kind: s', s, 's+1', s+1, 's-1', s-1
end program test
```

The output I receive:

```
 default real kind: r   17159400.0     r+1   17159400.0     r-1   17159400.0    
 r15 real kind: s   17159401.000000000      s+1   17159402.000000000      s-1   17159400.000000000
```

The result above means that 1 is below the accuracy of floating point variables with the default kind. I select a more accurate kind (`r15` here) that is accurate enough for your needs in the second line.

Comment: Why not showing the result for double precision as well? Please don't use kind=8 (even though OP used it as well) as this can differ per compiler.

Comment: @abinitio I added an example with explicit kinds on albert's suggestion.

Comment: Note that the accuracy of the integer is not really important here as it is the accuracy of the real variable that limited you.

Comment: More explicit is `use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env` and `integer, parameter :: sp = real32, dp = real64`.

Comment: @A.Hennink the `selected_real_kind` function depends on the target accuracy. `real32` and `real64`, although they often correspond to "float" and "double", merely prescribe a storage size.